# Unable to figure out a bug in this knapsack code?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am solving a [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PARTY/) spoj problem. Its been 3 days and I am unable to debug. My solution perfectly gives optimal value but it is not properly determining the items that are put in the knapsack to get the optimal value. The logic I used to store items that yield optimal solution is pretty popular but not working out for me. My code executes for the given test cases on spoj page. But fails for this particular one

```
7 2
6 1
5 1
```

My answer: 6 1
Correct answer: 5 1

This is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}


long knapsack(int n, int wt[], int value[], int W)
{
    int i, w, keep[n+1][W+1];
    long long dp[n+1][W+1];
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        dp[i][0] = 0;
        keep[i][0] = 0;
    }
    for(i=1;i<=W;i++)
    {
        dp[0][i] = 0;
        keep[0][i] = 0;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(w=1;w<=W;w++)
        {
            if(wt[i] <= w)
                dp[i][w] = max(value[i] + dp[i-1][w-wt[i]], dp[i-1][w]);

            else
                dp[i][w] = dp[i-1][w];
        }
    }

   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(w=0;w<=W;w++)
        {
            cout << dp[i][w] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    int k=W, sumw=0, sumv=0; i=n;

    while(i>0 && k>0)
    {
        if(dp[i][k]!=dp[i-1][k])
        {
            cout << "item: " << i << " taken " << "\n";
            sumw = sumw + wt[i];
            sumv = sumv + value[i];
            k = k-wt[i];
            i = i-1;
        }
        else
            i=i-1;
    }

    cout << sumw << " " << sumv << "\n";



}

int main()
{
    int items, i, W;
    cin >> W;
    cin >> items;
    while(W!=0 && items!=0)
    {
        int wt[items+1], value[items+1];
        for(i=1; i<=items; i++)
            cin >> wt[i] >> value[i];
        knapsack(items, wt, value, W);
        cin >> W >> items;

    }
}
```

Please help me debug if you got any ideas? Thanks so much!

PS: There are many spoj users with an exact same bug because of which they are getting WA, as seen in the comments.

Comment: Can you tell us what the significance of the test case is? I see two columns of data without any idea of what is what.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I forgot to mention. first line is (Total Weight, No of Items). From second line onwards its (weight of each item, value of item)

Comment: Well then you know logically your answer is correct, right? There's not a problem with *your* algorithm -- there's something wrong with **theirs**.

Comment: Nope. I know that my answer is wrong. For the test case given, I am getting the wrong answer. My algorithm is unable to break the tie. For example: if the values of two items is same, the item with the lower weight must be picked. But this case didn't seem to be covered when I implemented it by searching on the internet. Pretty much stuck here.

Comment: you don't need to keep track of items which you picked,once you obtained the optimal value you can traverse back the matrix dp to obtain the correct total weight.If you want the code I can refactor your code and post it.